# What is the difference between 'all' and 'each' in gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm working with Android Studio and the Gradle build script. When I was going to change some settings I needed to iterate some fields. But I have not very clear the difference between `all` and `each`.

For example I googled some code to change the output *apk* file name. The code iterates the `applicationVariants` by `all` and the `variant.outputs` by `each`:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
   variant.outputs.each { output ->
      output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, "MyApp.apk")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`each` is a plain groovy construct. It's used to iterate over a given object, does not modify it (original object) and returns the (unchanged) object after it finishes. See:

```
assert [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3].each { println it }
```

While `all` is a method added by gradle itself. So, `android` plugin adds [this](http://dcow.io/android-gradle-plugin-docs/com/android/build/gradle/AppExtension.html) extension, which has [`getApplicationVariants`](http://dcow.io/android-gradle-plugin-docs/com/android/build/gradle/AppExtension.html#getApplicationVariants()) method. Since groovy allows to omit `get`, just `applicationVariants` can be used. Now, the mentioned extension uses [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/DefaultDomainObjectSet.java) class to keep the collection of variants, which extends - [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java). In the latter `all` method is defined, as far as I see it's *just* a batch processing.

Comment: So the `each` is read-only to the container? But how the code, changing the `output.outputFile`, works?

Comment: Not exactly :) It changes the internal state of the object, it can be changed. E.g. You can use each to iterate a list of lists and add a random element to every list on the collection.

Comment: @jayatubi, is it clear now? If so, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late.

Comment: You're welcome. The more You use gradle to better the understanding is, you just need some time and experience. What is useful is to learn basics of groovy along with gradle.

Comment: In some sense, they are interchangeable for the inner loop. I have seen it as both `variant.outputs.each` and `variant.outputs.all` with identical results.

Comment: This doesn't explain what `all` does.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/DomainObjectCollection.html#all-groovy.lang.Closure-) for `DomainObjectCollection.all` says it "Executes the given closure against all objects in this collection, **and any objects subsequently added to this collection.**"

Comment: And what does "and any objects subsequently added to this collection" mean in this context?

Comment: @habitats It means that the closure is remembered, and when later a new element is added to the collection, the closure is applied to the newly added object.